# Access subview controls of a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel, subview

I added a UILabel as subview of a UIButton as

`var actLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(35, 0, 90, favHeight))
        actLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
        actLabel.text = "Actions"
        actLabel.textColor = darkBlueColor
        actLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        actPanel.addSubview(actLabel)`
where actPanel is a UIButton

On action of this UIButton I want to access the controls of this UILabel. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UIButton

```
class ActionButton : UIButton {
    var actionLabel: UILabel!
}

var actLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(35, 0, 90, favHeight))
actLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
actLabel.text = "Actions"
actLabel.textColor = darkBlueColor
actLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
actPanel.addSubview(actLabel)
actPanel.actionLabel = actLabel
```

Or build the smarts into the class

```
class ActionButton : UIButton {
    var favoriteHeight: CGFloat = 80 // Or whatever default you want.
    var darkBlueColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1) // Or whatever

    @IBOutlet var actionLabel: UILabel! {
        get {
            if _actionLabel == nil {
                var actLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(35, 0, 90, favoriteHeight))
                actLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
                actLabel.textColor = darkBlueColor
                actLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                addSubview(actLabel)

                _actionLabel = actLabel
            }
            return _actionLabel
        }
        set {
            _actionLabel?.removeFromSuperview()
            _actionLabel = newValue
            if let label = _actionLabel {
                addSubview(label)
            }
        }
    }

    override func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {
        // Ensure actionLabel exists and the text has a value.
        if actionLabel.text == nil || actionLabel.text!.isEmpty {
            actionLabel.text = "Action" // Provide a default value
        }
    }

    private var _actionLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all subviews by

```
var subviews = actPanel.subviews()
```

Then you can iterate through that array and find your label.

But if you have this label as title of the button, UIButton already has its own titleLabel.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a class for the actPanel and added the label as property you can access it with `actPanel.actLabel.text = "Actions"` else you can access it like you already did: `actLabel.text = "Actions"`